# create object from file and compare with method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating rectangle objects based off of info in a file. I need to go through each line in the file and make the various rectangles, and then compare them to each other and find out if they intersect. The values of a singular rectangle are stored on their own lines like: A,10,12,3,4 then B,3,5,62,2 and so on.

This is how I've been getting that info (I have a method in my class that prints out the values), but I can't figure out how to assign variable names to them so I can then do something like A.intersection(B), because right now I would have to say **sl[0].intersection(sl[0])** which just returns that they intersect perfectly on each other, because obviously they are the exact same rectangle.

```
def opens(f, cls): 
    try:
        inpFile = open(f)
    except IOError, e:
        print "Failed to open %s for reading: %s" % ("inputRectangles.txt", e)

    i = 0
    for line in inpFile:
        i+= 1
        sl = line.split(",")

        sl[1] = int(sl[1])
        sl[2] = int(sl[2])
        sl[3] = int(sl[3])
        sl[4] = int(sl[4])
        sl[0] = cls(sl[1], sl[2], sl[3], sl[4])
        print sl[0]

#MAIN        
opens("inputRectangles.txt", Rectangle)
```

So far I've tried to put each class into it's own list, and using random letter assignment in order to name them, but none of my potential solutions have worked. Part of the problem is I'm trying to write the code in a way that works no matter how many rectangles there are. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT
This is my intersection method:

```
    def intersection(self, other):

            #find unkown values of corners 
            #far right x (self)
            maxXS = self.__left + self.__width
            #top y (self)
            maxYS = self.__bottom + self.__height
            #far right x (other)
            maxXO = other.__left + other.__width
            #top y (other) 
            maxYO = other.__bottom + other.__height

            #find width(wx) and height(hy) 
            wx = min(maxXS, maxXO) - max(self.__left, other.__left)
            hy = min(maxYS, maxYO) - max(self.__bottom, other.__bottom)

            #if width less than 0 
            if wx < 0:
                wx = 0
            #ENDIF
            #if height less than 0
            if hy < 0:
                hy = 0
            #ENDIF

            #if min left point is self 
            if min(self.__left, other.__left) == self.__left:
                biggie = other
                smalls = self 
            else:
                biggie = self
                smalls = other
            #ENDIF

            #find lower left point of new rect  
            miniLY = max(smalls.__left, biggie.__left) 
            miniLX = max(smalls.__bottom, biggie.__bottom)

            #if width and height are 0
            #then minimum points 0
            if wx == 0 and hy == 0:
                miniLX = 0
                miniLY = 0
            #ENDIF
            #return new rect with calculated values 
            return Rectangle(miniLX, miniLY, wx, hy)
        #ENDMETHOD
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you would actually be doing something like `A.intersection(B)`? Are you taking that from user input?

Comment: I added my intersection code. Basically when I call A.intersection(B) it will be with the rectangles I pulled from a .txt file which already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should collect the rectangles in a list:

```
rects = []
for line in inpFile:
    sl = line.split(",")
    rects.append(cls(*map(int, sl[1:5])))

# now that you have them all, you can do
rects[0].intersection(rects[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you just need to create a list of rectangles inside your fuction, which you finally return and then you can call the intersection method once you have different rectangles.

```
 def opens(f, cls): 
    try:
        inpFile = open(f)
    except IOError, e:
        print "Failed to open %s for reading: %s" % ("inputRectangles.txt", e)


    list_rectangles = []

    for line in inpFile:

        sl = line.split(",")

        sl[1] = int(sl[1])
        sl[2] = int(sl[2])
        sl[3] = int(sl[3])
        sl[4] = int(sl[4])

        rectangle = (cls(sl[1], sl[2], sl[3], sl[4])
        list_rectangles.append(rectangle)


    return list_rectangles

#MAIN        
list_rectangles = opens("inputRectangles.txt", Rectangle) 

rectangle_1 = list_rectangles[0]
rectangle_2 = list_rectangles[1]
rectangle_1 .intersection(rectangle_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you wanted to collect the intersecting rectangles, so here is a solution that generates pairs of rectangles that intersect.

```
from Rectangle import Rectangle

def readfile(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                yield line
    except IOError as e:
        print "Failed to open %s for reading: %s" % ("inputRectangles.txt", e)

def find_intersections(rectangles):
    rectangle_list = list(rectangles)
    r1 = rectangle_list.pop(0)
    while rectangle_list:
        for r2 in rectangle_list:
            if r1.intersection(r2):
                yield r1, r2
        r1 = rectangle_list.pop(0)

lines = readfile("inputRectangles.txt")
rectangles = [Rectangle(line.split(',')) for line in lines]
intersecting_rectangles = list(find_intersections(rectangles))
```